# Debug FastAPI launch.json

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

I would appreciate some help!

I have been trying all afternoon to set up my launch.json to debug my fastAPI aplication ans as I am quite new on this things I still haven't managed to do so...
To put you in situation, this is my folder structure:

```
MyFolder 
  | - .vscode
  |         | - launch.json
  | - graph-storage
  |         | - app
  |         |       | - server
  |         |       |          | - features/
  |         |       |          | - models/
  |         |       |          | - routes/
  |         |       |          | - services/
  |         |       |          | - app.py
  |         |       |          | - database.py
  |         |       |          | - __init__.py
  |         |       | - __init__.py
  |         |       | - main.py
  |         | - venv/
  |         | - requirements.txt
  | - .gitignore
  | - .dev.env
```

In my main.py I have the following:

```
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("server.app:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```

And in my app.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

from app.server.routes.graph_routes import router as GraphRouter

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(GraphRouter, tags=["Graph"], prefix="/graph")

@app.get("/", tags=["Root"])
async def read_root():
    return {"message": "Welcome to this fantastic app!"}
```

My launch.json is the following:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    
    {
      "name": "Python: FastAPI",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "uvicorn",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/graph-storage",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.dev.env",
      "args": [
        "app.server.app:app",
        "--reload"
      ],
      
      "jinja": true,
      "justMyCode": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I have selected my venviroment in VS code:
[image: VS code Interpreter selection]

And my venv has the required packages:

```
(venv) alexabades@Alex-Abades-Laptop:~/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage$ pip list
Package           Version
----------------- ------------
annotated-types   0.6.0
anyio             3.7.1
black             23.10.0
click             8.1.7
dnspython         2.4.2
exceptiongroup    1.1.3
fastapi           0.103.2
h11               0.14.0
idna              3.4
motor             3.3.1
mypy-extensions   1.0.0
numpy             1.26.1
packaging         23.2
pandas            2.1.2
pathspec          0.11.2
pip               23.3.2
platformdirs      3.11.0
pydantic          2.4.2
pydantic_core     2.10.1
pymongo           4.5.0
python-dateutil   2.8.2
pytz              2023.3.post1
setuptools        59.6.0
six               1.16.0
sniffio           1.3.0
starlette         0.27.0
tomli             2.0.1
typing_extensions 4.8.0
tzdata            2023.3
uvicorn           0.23.2
```

I also have set the .dev.env as:

```
PYTHONPATH = /home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage
```

I have managed to access the debug console, basically it stops in my breakpoint. The problem araises whhen I use any of the dependencies like pandas. I don't know how to activate my venv but the console gives me:

```
(venv) (base) alexabades@Alex-Abades-Laptop:~/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage$  cd /home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage/graph-storage/ ; /usr/bin/env /home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage/venv/bin/python /home/alexabades/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 37511 -- -m uvicorn app.server.app:app --reload 
bash: cd: /home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage/graph-storage/: No such file or directory
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [18504] using StatReload
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 61, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 68, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 467, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage/app/server/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.server.routes.graph_routes import router as GraphRouter
  File "/home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage/app/server/routes/graph_routes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from app.server.features.retrieve_tag_relationship.retrieve_tag_relationship_feature import (
  File "/home/alexabades/neocareu-api-recomsyst/graph-storage/app/server/features/retrieve_tag_relationship/retrieve_tag_relationship_feature.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I have tried adding this lines to the launch.json, but the vscode states **The Python path in your debug configuration is invalid.**

```
"python": "${workspaceFolder}/graph-storage/venv/bin/python", 
"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/graph-storage"},
```

Additionally, and I don't know why I have to do this, I have to run the below command before being able to run my app.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PWD
```

Could someone help me to figure out how to specify my venv to the launch.json?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on error log,, throwing `pandas` not found.  you are in `venv`, does `pip show pandas` shows the package? if not most likely the venv does not have all the modules from the requirement.txt

Comment: Have you tried to make sure you are in the right `venv`? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: @simpleApp Hello, It does, I just added the info, when I access to my venv and I list the packages installed, there're all the packages stated in my requirements.txt

Comment: @BernardL Hello! Tes, I have the venv pointed, but it seems like it's not being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

So basically I managed to solve my problem. It seems like I had a wierd problem in the venv...
I just deleted my venv and I created a new one, installed all the packages and I defined my launch.json as:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: FastAPI",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "uvicorn",
      "args": [
        "app.server.app:app",
        "--reload"
      ],
      "jinja": true,
      "justMyCode": true,
      "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/graph-storage"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not quite sure why my venv wasn't detecting the pandas package ....